# Minimizing inconsistency between tables in denormalized databases like Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql, consistency, denormalization

Cassandra (and BigTable, etc) recommends a denormalized database, where tables are designed from the expected queries. The [Cassandra doc](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/data_modeling/data_modeling_logical.html) uses this example:

```
hotels_by_poi:   poi_name (Key)
                 hotel_id (Cluster key)
                 name
                 phone
                 address

hotels:          hotel_id (Key)
                 name
                 phone
                 address
```

So name, phone, and address are denormalized between `hotels_by_poi` and `hotels`. What I'm wondering about is how to implement this method:

```
update_hotel_info(hotel_id, name, phone, address) {
    updateHotel(hotel_id, name, phone, address);
    updatePoisByHotel(hotel_id, name, phone, address);

}
```

It's possible the first method errors, or that the server running the two methods errors between the first and second update methods. Therefore the data gets out of sync. Without doing anything else, it's not even eventually consistent.

- Is it possible to design multiple tables for eventual consistency of denormalized data shared between them?
- Is this something people worry about in practice? (e.g., if the services are all 5 9's, then the integrity is 4 9s, pretty good.)

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to wrap the related table updates in a CQL `BATCH` statement as I've explained here -- https://community.datastax.com/articles/2744/.

Even if you didn't use CQL batches, the idea is that if either of those methods fail, you should have error handling that would (for example) retry the request to make sure they're successful. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, +1. I'll not "accept" yet because there's probably multiple approaches to how to solve this especially because one of the advertisements of Cassandra is that it's cheap writes which this cancels out.

Comment: I don't quite understand how "this cancels out". Could you please elaborate? Writes are cheap as you said so writing what is duplicated data is cheap and we do it because it optimises reads. Cheers!

Comment: What if I have many different slice and dice views for the same entity? For example comments_by_video, comments_by_user, comments_by_date, comments_by_length, comments_by_status etc? Batches is the only way to support data integrity?

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov "data integrity" is for the most part a different concept to what CQL batches are designed for. But yes, you need to place the "duplicate" writes to multiple tables in a CQL batch to keep the entries for the same entity synchronised across tables. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @ErickRamirez. I meant data consistency between tables. Looking if it's possible to migrate highly relational data with lots of tables and foreign keys to anything like Cassandra to ensure better scalability and availability. My database has lots of tables, services have lots of APIs which operates with same type of entity. For example I have APIs like getUsersByNickname, getUsersByGroup, getUsersByOrg, getUsersByTag etc. Thinking in terms of Cassandra I feel I will need to create multiple tables with different partition keys for the same user. User has lots of fields and attributes 1/2

Comment: And org, groups and tags have its own attributes. In case of user insert, update or delete I will have to update multiple tables. Also in case of group, tag or org update I will have to update table as well. And this makes think it will be difficult to support considering high load and muti region setup. Maybe cassandra not the best fit for such type of data?

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov please start a new post so we're not forever having a "conversation" in the comments section. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As @Erick mentioned either use batch for maintaining consistency or if you can handle at client side by retrying failed inserts/deletes. For example

```
update_hotel_info(hotel_id, name, phone, address) {
    updateHotel(hotel_id, name, phone, address);
    updatePoisByHotel(hotel_id, name, phone, address);
}
```

You can retry `update_hotel_info` if either of the insert/update failed . This way you will get fast writes and you can use cheap writes of Cassandra.